# How to check if a string contains any of the elements in an string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search

I'm trying to implement a simple search function. I have a string array which contains all words which was typed in from the user to search. And I have another string which contains data like User Name, content... So what I want to do is to check is Name contains any of the elements in the search or String array. Right now I have a loop which checks one word at a time and concatenates the result in an IEnumerable.

Does anyone know a faster way of doing this search? Like String.ContainsAny(Search[])

Comment: Is this array pre-sorted, our does it make sense to in your case? That would change the "best" algorithm.

Comment: Its random, so the search can be Search = ["Admin", "Hello"] and I have to search through a string = "This is my post, Hello".

Comment: Without any kind of sorting, than I don't know of any algorithm that is faster than a simple linear search, as many Answers below mention with the use of Any(). Depending on when/how the array is created, and how often the array is used repeatedly without rebuilding, it may be faster to sort it first, then search with a different algorithm. But we'll need more context to your usage before we can suggest the best algorithm.

Comment: <code>
s = "admin is here"; 
IEnumerable<Post> posts = from p in post_repository.Posts where p.Content.Contains(s) || p.Author.Contains(s) || p.ContactEmail.Contains(s) select p;
</code>

Comment: The comment above is part of the code, didnt know about 5 mins to edit.
I'm sorry for the horrible formatting. Thats the search I'm doing right now but the problem is that it searches for the whole phrase in string s. But I want to make it search each word. So I split the string s into parts. After that I got an array of strings. Now I have to find an efficient way of searching, thats where I'm stuck.

Comment: Is `post_repository` in a database that has indexing or full-text search capabilities? Or is it always an in-memory structure you build yourself?

Comment: Its in-memory built myself. Right now I'm trying to add an extension method to class string but LINQ doesnt like it. I saw a work around, I'll try to see if it works.

Comment: You didn't answer how often you re-use the list to search through. If it is read from more than it is recreated/updated, you could sort it first.

Comment: You could look into an indexing engine like Lucene.Net: http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/ but the underlying data store may or may not be an issue depending on what you use.

Comment: The amount of use may be very high cause there is no limit to posts and the number of search terms could be high. That's why I really want to avoid a huge loop. Ill start reading the link you gave, thanks BTW. I appreciate all the help you guys are giving.

Comment: The posts are never deleted, theoretically it will stay there forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Search.Any(p => name.Contains(p))
```

Comment: `Does anyone know a faster way of doing this search?` Is that different algorithm than in question? Really faster?

Comment: As far as I know, the default object provider Any() method does a linear search until it fines one. So worst case is O(N).

Comment: I'm implementing it right now but alittle confused. What does 'p' mean in the code? Thanks

Comment: @user1034489: It's the new C# 3.0 shortcut syntax. It basically is a new method argument, that you see it used in the method body (`name.Contains(p)`) — that bit right there is the whole method body. Read up on how LINQ works for more info.

Comment: @user1034489 http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-the-lambda-operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx   But be aware, shorter code does not make it faster

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;

string[] searchItems = ...
string input = "This is the input text";

// Check whether at least one match found
bool matchFound = input.Any(w => input.Contains(w));

// Count all matches
int matchesCount = input.Where(w => input.Contains(w))
                        .Count();
```

Comment: I'm confused... `searchItems` is never used in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] searchItems = ...;
string[] userNames = ...;

var matches = userNames.Intersect(searchItems);
```

You can find more about the intersect method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this...

```
return array.Any(s => s.Equals(myString))
```

or try like this....

```
 string stringToCheck = "text1";
        string[] stringArray = { "text1", "testtest", "test1test2", "test2text1" };
        foreach (string x in stringArray)
        {
            if (x.Contains(stringToCheck))
            {
                // Process...
            }

        }
```

or Something like this

```
string stringToCheck = "text1text2text3";
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "text1" };
if (Array.Exists<string>(stringArray, (Predicate<string>)delegate(string s) { 
    return stringToCheck.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1; })) {
    Console.WriteLine("Found!");
}
```

Comment: How would you adapt your first version to allow case-invariant comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions to this problem for example:

1. Solution 1

   ```
   private void findDateColumn()   {
           string stringToCheck = "date";
           int stringToCheckIndex = -1;
           string elementInArray = "Not Defined or Not Found";
           if (Array.Exists<string> (headers, (Predicate<string>) delegate (string s)
           {
           stringToCheckIndex = s.IndexOf (stringToCheck,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
           elementInArray = s;
           return stringToCheckIndex > -1;
           }))
           {
           dateColTitle.Text = elementInArray; //a textbox to show the output
           }
   }
   ```
2. Solution 2

I'm using @Lev answer, which seems simpler and shorter plus giving the same result:

```
    private void setDateColumnTitle ()
{

dateColTitle.Text = "Not Defined or Not Found";

var match = headers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IndexOf("date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1);

if (match!=null)                
    dateColTitle.Text = match;               
}
```